# How do i count occurences of an array written in an input field?

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

```
window.onload = oppstart;
var string=[];

function oppstart() {
document.getElementById("knapp").onclick=knapp;
}

function knapp(){
var felt = document.getElementById("felt").value;

var array = new Array();
array = felt.split(",");

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  console.log(array[i]);

}
var skrivUt = document.getElementById("utskrift");
              document.getElementById("utskrift").innerHTML = " ";

}
```

So i have an input field called "Felt" in HTML. When the user types in numbers "1,2,3,4,5" etc. i splits them and puts them in the console log without commas. What i want to do after i have my values, is count the occurrences of the numbers and print the results out on my innerHTML "skrivUT"

Comment: Add this in the end of function `knapp`: `skrivUt.innerHTML = ""+array.length+"";`.

Comment: It just counts the amount of indexes, not the occurences

Answer (score 0):

You could take tha array and use an object for counting the occurence of single values. After counting show the object.

The count works with an object without any prototypes and it checks if a property with a truthy value is a avalable, then just increment the counter. In the oser case assign the first count to the property.

```js
window.onload = oppstart;

function getPlural(number, word) {
    return number === 1 && word.one || word.other;
}

function joinNice(array) {
    var a = array.slice(); // take copy, prevent mutation of array
    return a.concat(a.splice(-2, 2).join(' and ')).join(', ');
}

function oppstart() {
    document.getElementById("knapp").onclick = knapp;
}

function knapp() {
    var count = Object.create(null),
        felt = document.getElementById("felt").value,
        skrivUt = document.getElementById("utskrift"),
        array = felt.split(","),
        i;

    for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (count[array[i]]) {
            ++count[array[i]];
        } else {
            count[array[i]] = 1;
        }
    }

    utskrift.innerHTML = 'You wrote: ' + joinNice(Object.keys(count).map(function (k) {
        return count[k] + ' ' + getPlural(count[k], time) + ' item ' + k;
    })) + '.';
}

var time = { one: 'time', other: 'times' };
```

```html
<input id="felt"> <button id="knapp">submit</button>
<p id="utskrift"></p>
```

Comment: I like the way you explained this! Thank you. When i ran the code snippet of yours i got brackets printed out aswell. Is that supposed to happen? I’m on mobile phone atm so i can’t test out the code yet

Comment: right, you get the whole object in the output. if you like to get another formatted output, you nedd to iterate over the keys and values. how the result should look like is missing in the question.

Comment: I see! is there any other way to do it without object and JSON?

Comment: no, without object, yes, witout JSON. but you have not given a wanted format for the output.

Comment: So lets say i write "1,1,1,2,3,3," in my input field, i want the output on the innerHTML to be "You have written 3 amount of index (1), 1 amount of index (2),  2 amount of index (3)" ETC.